# 4k Display on macbook pro 15 retina late 2013 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz, but with scaled fonts

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, displayport

I am using an external 4k display (from LG a 27 inch display: LG_27MU67-B) on displayport on my MacBook Pro Retina 15 inch (late 2013).
3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz works out of the box. Cool!

But..
I want to use 4K, but with scaled fonts, like on my retina display. So I did scaling in System Preferences to "looks like" 2560 x 1440.
Showing display preferences on terminal says something different:

```
$ system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

* current status:

```
Displays:
    Color LCD:
      Display Type: Retina LCD
      Resolution: 2880 x 1800 Retina #(is scaled, but resolution is nevertheless  2880 x 1800)
      Retina: Yes
      Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Built-In: Yes
    27MU67:
      Resolution: 2560 x 1440 @ 60 Hz #(is scaled, but resolution should be 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz)
      Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: Supported
      Connection Type: DisplayPort
      Television: Yes
```

- is to be:

  ```
  27MU67:
    Resolution: 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz
  ```

What can I do to use my 4K display with 4k, but scaled fonts?